# Rowspan/Cellspan for only Headers (not for data cells) in DOJO grid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid

I need create dojo grid with next structure:
[image]
How can we see on requirements image, grid has grouping in only headers and cells with data have usual structure without any mergers.
If we add colspan/rowspan to structure(layout) dojo grid, the grid will create the same layout for header and for cells with data.
But this behavior is incorrect for us. 
My questuin is:
 Is there possibility to make headers with colspan and rowspan without affecting for data cells?